# Current user is the previous one when logout and login again flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

hi evreyone i'm kind new to flutter i'm using flutter_bloc 7.1.0 as I mentioned in the title when I log out and log in again I get the previous user credential. can anyone help me please

this is the main function

```
import 'package:centredeformation/screens/layout/centre_app/centre_layout.dart';
import 'package:centredeformation/screens/layout/centre_app/cubit/cubit.dart';
import 'package:centredeformation/screens/layout/centre_app/cubit/states.dart';

import 'package:centredeformation/screens/product/products_screen.dart';
import 'package:centredeformation/screens/shared/bloc_observer.dart';
import 'package:centredeformation/screens/shared/components/constants.dart';
import 'package:centredeformation/screens/shared/network/local/cache_helper.dart';

import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';


import 'screens/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'util/const.dart';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();
  //DioHelper.init();
  await CacheHelper.init();

  //bool isDark = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'isDark');

  Widget widget;

  //bool onBoarding = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'onBoarding');
  //token = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'token');

  uId = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'uId');

  // if(onBoarding != null)
  // {
  //   if(token != null) widget = ShopLayout();
  //   else widget = ShopLoginScreen();
  // } else
  //   {
  //     widget = OnBoardingScreen();
  //   }

  if(uId != null)
  {
    //   CacheHelper.removeData(
    //    key: 'uId',
    // );
    widget = CentreLayout();
  } else
  {
    widget = WelcomeScreen();
  }

  runApp(MyApp(
    
    startWidget: widget,
  ));
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget
{

  final Widget startWidget;

  MyApp({
    
    this.startWidget,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [

        BlocProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context) => CentreCubit()..getUserData()..getPosts()..getAllFormateurs()..getAllStudents()..getComputerScienceCourses()..getDevelopmentCourses()..getDesignCourses()..getLeadershipCourses()..getCourses(),
        ),
      ],
      child: BlocConsumer<CentreCubit, CentreStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          print('the main uid is');
          print(uId);
          return MaterialApp(
            // debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: Constants.lightTheme,
            darkTheme: Constants.darkTheme,
            themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
            //themeMode: AppCubit.get(context).isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
            home: WelcomeScreen(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the Cubit  code and the function that return user data

```
class CentreCubit extends Cubit<CentreStates> {
  CentreCubit() : super(CentreStatesInitialState());

  static CentreCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);

  SocialUserModel userModel = new SocialUserModel();

  void getUserData() {
    emit(CentreStatesGetUserLoadingState());

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uId).get().then((value) {
      print(value.data());
      userModel = SocialUserModel.fromJson(value.data());
      print('the user model is :');
      print(userModel);
      // if(userModel.isFormateur) {
      //   print('adminlogin');
      //   emit(CentreGetAdminSuccessState());
      // }else{
      //
      // }
      print('not admin Login');
      emit(CentreGetUserSuccessState());
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
      emit(CentreGetUserErrorState(error.toString()));
    });
  }
```

and this is the login function

```
class CentreLoginCubit extends Cubit<CentreLoginStates> {
  CentreLoginCubit() : super(CentreLoginInitialState());

  static CentreLoginCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);

  void userLogin({
    @required String email,
    @required String password,
  }) {
    emit(CentreLoginLoadingState());

    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    )
        .then((value) {

      print(value.user.email);
      print(value.user.uid);
      emit(CentreLoginSuccessState(value.user.uid));
    }).catchError((error) {
      emit(CentreLoginErrorState(error.toString()));
    });
  }
}
```

and this is the login screen :

```
class CentreLoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final String assetLogin= 'assets/images/secure_login.svg';
  static const String id='SocialLoginScreen';
  var formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var emailController = TextEditingController();
  var passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => CentreLoginCubit(),
      child: BlocConsumer<CentreLoginCubit, CentreLoginStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is CentreLoginErrorState) {
            showToast(
              text: state.error,
              state: ToastStates.ERROR,
            );
          }

          if (state is CentreLoginSuccessState) {
            //uId = state.uId;
            CacheHelper.saveData(
              key: 'uId',
              value: state.uId,
            ).then((value) async {
              //uId = await CacheHelper.getData(key: 'uId');
              print('the uid sign in is');
              print(uId);
              uId = state.uId;
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(state.uId).get().then((value){
                var model = SocialUserModel.fromJson(value.data());
                if(model.isFormateur){
                  navigateAndFinish(
                    context,
                    AdminHome(),
                  );
                }else {
                  navigateAndFinish(
                    context,
                    CentreLayout(),
                  );
                }
              }).catchError((error){
                print(error.toString());
              });

            });
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                     child:Form(
                      key: formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'LOGIN',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                           SvgPicture.asset(
                              assetLogin,
                              semanticsLabel: 'Acme Logo',
                              width: 300,

                            ),


                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30.0,
                          ),
                          defaultFormField(
                            controller: emailController,
                            type: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            validate: (String value) {
                              if (value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'please enter your email address';
                              }
                            },
                            label: 'Email Address',
                            prefix: Icons.email_outlined,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15.0,
                          ),
                          defaultFormField(
                            controller: passwordController,
                            type: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                            suffix: CentreLoginCubit.get(context).suffix,
                            onSubmit: (value) {
                              if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                CentreLoginCubit.get(context).userLogin(
                                  email: emailController.text,
                                  password: passwordController.text,
                                );
                              }
                            },
                            isPassword: CentreLoginCubit.get(context).isPassword,
                            suffixPressed: () {
                              CentreLoginCubit.get(context)
                                  .changePasswordVisibility();
                            },
                            validate: (String value) {
                              if (value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'password is too short';
                              }
                            },
                            label: 'Password',
                            prefix: Icons.lock_outline,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 30.0,
                          ),
                          ConditionalBuilder(
                            condition: state is! CentreLoginLoadingState,
                            builder: (context) => defaultButton(
                              function: () {


                                if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                  CentreLoginCubit.get(context).userLogin(
                                    email: emailController.text,
                                    password: passwordController.text,
                                  );
                                  // navigateTo(
                                  //     context,
                                  //     //MainScreen()
                                  //   CentreLayout()
                                  // );
                                }
                              },
                              text: 'login',
                              isUpperCase: true,
                            ),
                            fallback: (context) =>
                                Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15.0,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Don\'t have an account?',
                              ),
                              defaultTextButton(
                                function: () {
                                  navigateTo(
                                    context,
                                    CentreRegisterScreen(),
                                  );
                                },
                                text: 'register',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ),
              ),
            ),

          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your code to ensure that you have properly signed the user out by calling the `signOut()` method like this `await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();`
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#signing-out

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that getUserData() is only called one time when the app start .to correct this i just call the method getUserData() when sign in

```
if (state is CentreLoginSuccessState) {
            //uId = state.uId;
            CacheHelper.saveData(
              key: 'uId',
              value: state.uId,
            ).then((value) async {
              print('im getting');
              uId =state.uId;
              print('the uid sign in is');
              print(uId);
              uId = state.uId;
              CentreCubit.get(context).getUserData();
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(state.uId).get().then((value){
                var model = SocialUserModel.fromJson(value.data());
                if(model.isFormateur){
                  navigateAndFinish(
                    context,
                    AdminHome(),
                  );
                }else {
                  navigateAndFinish(
                    context,
                    CentreLayout(),
                  );
                }
              }).catchError((error){
                print(error.toString());
              });

            });
          }
```

i add just this line :

```
 CentreCubit.get(context).getUserData();
```